# load balancer act weird

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created 2 instances for my website and connected them to Amazon load balancer. I have placed the `DNS name` of the load balancer into `CNAME` so people can view my website from my domain:

```
*.domain.com
```

and

```
www.domain.com
```

Now people can visit my website and it works. The problem is that if people go to `domain.com` then the load balancer only shows the first instance, but if people go into `www.domain.com` then the load balancer switches between the instances which is perfect.

Why does that happen and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you know that it is only serving traffic from one instance?

Answer (score 0):

Using a CNAME record in the zone apex is not supported under the DNS standard and can cause no end of issues with downstream caching DNS servers doing unexpected things with the result. I can't confirm with 100% certainty that this is what is causing your issue but I am reasonably sure that it is and even if it isn't it is certainly good practice to bring your DNS configuration to standard.

In your Route 53 configuration for the zone apex record leave the record set name blank, set the type to "A", and select the alias radio box to "yes", then click on alias target and it will populate a list of supported endpoints under your account, choose your load balancer shown under "ELB load balancers".

AWS doesn't do the best job explaining this but while you are correct in using a CNAME record to target the ELB from www.domain.com the zone apex record needs to be done as an alias which Route 53 will turn into a standard "A" record to return for DNS queries but will return the IP of the ELB instance at that point in time with a low time to live to ensure that when the IP changes cached records don't cause an issue.

I suspect this may solve your problem here, as your upstream DNS provider may be having issues with the zone apex CNAME and so is taking the IP of the destination server and is caching that instead. After you complete the changes to your Route 53 configuration wait 6-24 hours to take into account how long your upstream DNS provider is caching the record for or manually set your DNS server to an alternate DNS server which you have not used before such as Google's public DNS servers located at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Hope this helps.